# How to pick the pre selected date/time

Tags: ios, objective-c, timepicker

I am building an iOS app and in this app I got a datepicker (timepicker mode).
When user clicks the button and the picker opens one date/time is "selected". For example 1:20 am (I use 5 minutes intervals) but when the user dismiss the picker it picks the real time which is 1:23 am. If I pick another date/time by scrolling and then selects 1:20 am again I get that time. But not if I don´t do any active selection.

My question is this. How can I get the time that is selected by default (if no user interaction is done)?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Did you set the date of the UIDatePicker at start?

Comment: No, it uses the default

Comment: Then, you may want to set one (using `NSDateComponents`) that's according to your settings (each 5 minutes).